# What does a symbol with an arrow pointing to the upper right mean?

Tags: schematics, symbol

[image]

Full Circuit Below

[image]

I looked through multiple sites that includes a lot of different symbols and I have no idea what this is.

Comment: Some more context what kind of diagram you looking at would help. Isolated as it is here I would interpret is as an indicator for voltage or current.

Comment: Added. I understand the rest of the feedback Op-Amp circuit

Comment: That little box to the left is an ionization chamber FYI

Comment: Yep! That is a voltage indicator. The text next to it says so: V = ....

Comment: I thought a voltmeter was a circle with a V in it?

Comment: I think the confusion is caused by the fact that the symbol represents a moving coil meter while most meters today are digital.

Comment: Perfect ok thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's some sort of meter, and between an op-amp output and ground it can only be a voltmeter.